# Не получается сделать сортировку слов по столбцам PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

я хочу реализовать сортировку слов по столбцам, однако какую информацию я бы не вводил, всё равно выводит правильный ответ. Почему так происходит?

код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(688, 548)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 160, 221))
    self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
    self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
    self.AnswerLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.AnswerLine.setObjectName("AnswerLine")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.AnswerLine)
    self.AnswerLine2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.AnswerLine2.setObjectName("AnswerLine2")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.AnswerLine2)
    self.AnswerLine3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.AnswerLine3.setObjectName("AnswerLine3")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.AnswerLine3)
    self.AnswerLine4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
    self.AnswerLine4.setObjectName("AnswerLine4")
    self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.AnswerLine4)
    self.SetButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.SetButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 290, 101, 41))
    self.SetButton.setObjectName("SetButton")
    self.CheckButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.CheckButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 290, 111, 41))
    self.CheckButton.setObjectName("CheckButton")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 420, 341, 91))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 350, 151, 41))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.verticalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 30, 160, 221))
    self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_2")
    self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
    self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
    self.AnswerLine_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
    self.AnswerLine_2.setObjectName("AnswerLine_2")
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.AnswerLine_2)
    self.AnswerLine2_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
    self.AnswerLine2_2.setObjectName("AnswerLine2_2")
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.AnswerLine2_2)
    self.AnswerLine3_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
    self.AnswerLine3_2.setObjectName("AnswerLine3_2")
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.AnswerLine3_2)
    self.AnswerLine4_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
    self.AnswerLine4_2.setObjectName("AnswerLine4_2")
    self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.AnswerLine4_2)
    self.SetButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.SetButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 280, 101, 41))
    self.SetButton_2.setObjectName("SetButton_2")
    self.CheckButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.CheckButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 280, 111, 41))
    self.CheckButton_2.setObjectName("CheckButton_2")
    self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 340, 151, 41))
    self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 688, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    self.SetButton.clicked.connect(self.setanswer)
    self.CheckButton.clicked.connect(self.checkanswer)
    self.SetButton_2.clicked.connect(self.setanswer2)
    self.CheckButton_2.clicked.connect(self.checkanswer2)

def setanswer(self):
    self.a = self.AnswerLine.text()
    self.b = self.AnswerLine2.text()
    self.c = self.AnswerLine3.text()
    self.d = self.AnswerLine4.text()

def checkanswer(self):
    if str(self.a) == "Car" or "Plane" or "Boat" or "Rocket" and\
    str(self.b) == "Car" or "Plane" or "Boat" or "Rocket" and\
    str(self.c) == "Car" or "Plane" or "Boat" or "Rocket" and\
    str(self.d) == "Car" or "Plane" or "Boat" or "Rocket":
        self.label_2.setText("Well done!")
    else:
        self.label_2.setText("No(")

def setanswer2(self):
    self.a1 = self.AnswerLine_2.text()
    self.b1 = self.AnswerLine2_2.text()
    self.c1 = self.AnswerLine3_2.text()
    self.d1 = self.AnswerLine4_2.text()

def checkanswer2(self):
    if str(self.a1) == "Building" or "Home" or "Flat" or "Room" and\
    str(self.b1) == "Building" or "Home" or "Flat" or "Room" and\
    str(self.c1) == "Building" or "Home" or "Flat" or "Room" and\
    str(self.d1) == "Building" or "Home" or "Flat" or "Room":
        self.label_3.setText("Well Done!")

    else:
        self.label_3.setText("Please Try Again")

 def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.SetButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set Answers"))
    self.CheckButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Check Answer"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "List of words: Car, Plane, Boat, Rocket, Building, Home, Flat, Room"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
    self.SetButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set Answers"))
    self.CheckButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Check Answer"))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Странно, но  вам уже писал: `Первое, что вы должны запомнить - НИКОГДА НЕ изменяйте модуль созданный в QT Designer. НИКОГДА.`. Если вас этому учат - значит вас учат не правильно.

Comment: Вы попали в одну из самых распространенных ошибок PyQt: вы редактируете файл, сгенерированный утилитой pyuic. Эти файлы не предназначены для отправной точки для запуска вашей программы, но они всегда должны использоваться как импортированные модули. Я предлагаю вам внимательно прочитать документацию по использованию Designer https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html .

Comment: Извините, с первого раза не дошло про редактирование модуля, осознал свои ошибки, впредь так делать не буду.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что вы должны запомнить - **НИКОГДА НЕ изменяйте модуль созданный в QT Designer**. **НИКОГДА**.

Вы должны воспринимать этот модуль как файл ресурсов.

Создайте класс и наполните его тем что вы создали в QT Designer.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(688, 548)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 160, 221))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.AnswerLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.AnswerLine.setObjectName("AnswerLine")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.AnswerLine)
        self.AnswerLine2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.AnswerLine2.setObjectName("AnswerLine2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.AnswerLine2)
        self.AnswerLine3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.AnswerLine3.setObjectName("AnswerLine3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.AnswerLine3)
        self.AnswerLine4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.AnswerLine4.setObjectName("AnswerLine4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.AnswerLine4)
        self.SetButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.SetButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 290, 101, 41))
        self.SetButton.setObjectName("SetButton")
        self.CheckButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.CheckButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 290, 111, 41))
        self.CheckButton.setObjectName("CheckButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 420, 341, 91))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 350, 151, 41))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(370, 30, 160, 221))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.AnswerLine_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.AnswerLine_2.setObjectName("AnswerLine_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.AnswerLine_2)
        self.AnswerLine2_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.AnswerLine2_2.setObjectName("AnswerLine2_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.AnswerLine2_2)
        self.AnswerLine3_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.AnswerLine3_2.setObjectName("AnswerLine3_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.AnswerLine3_2)
        self.AnswerLine4_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
        self.AnswerLine4_2.setObjectName("AnswerLine4_2")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.AnswerLine4_2)
        self.SetButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.SetButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 280, 101, 41))
        self.SetButton_2.setObjectName("SetButton_2")
        self.CheckButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.CheckButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 280, 111, 41))
        self.CheckButton_2.setObjectName("CheckButton_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 340, 151, 41))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 688, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.SetButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set Answers"))
        self.CheckButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Check Answer"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "List of words: Car, Plane, Boat, Rocket, Building, Home, Flat, Room"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.SetButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Set Answers"))
        self.CheckButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Check Answer"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.SetButton.clicked.connect(self.setanswer)
        self.CheckButton.clicked.connect(self.checkanswer)
        self.SetButton_2.clicked.connect(self.setanswer2)
        self.CheckButton_2.clicked.connect(self.checkanswer2)
        
        self.a, self.b, self.c, self.d = '', '', '', '',             
        self.list_words = ["Car", "Plane", "Boat", "Rocket"]
        self.list_words_2 = ["Building", "Home", "Flat", "Room"]

    def setanswer(self):                  
        self.a = self.AnswerLine.text()
        self.b = self.AnswerLine2.text()
        self.c = self.AnswerLine3.text()
        self.d = self.AnswerLine4.text()

    def checkanswer(self):
        self.setanswer()
        if self.a in  self.list_words and self.b in  self.list_words and\
           self.c in  self.list_words and self.d  in  self.list_words:
            self.label_2.setText("Well done!")
        else:
            self.label_2.setText("No(")

    def setanswer2(self):                  
        self.a1 = self.AnswerLine_2.text()
        self.b1 = self.AnswerLine2_2.text()
        self.c1 = self.AnswerLine3_2.text()
        self.d1 = self.AnswerLine4_2.text()

    def checkanswer2(self):
        self.setanswer2()
        if self.a1 in  self.list_words_2 and self.b1 in  self.list_words_2 and\
           self.c1 in  self.list_words_2 and self.d1  in  self.list_words_2:
            self.label_3.setText("Well Done!")
        else:
            self.label_3.setText("Please Try Again")        


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
#    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#    MainWindow.show()
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]